# Feature Request: tag autocompletion in Search

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-search, tag-autocomplete

Searching with tags is much, much more effective than searching without. Unfortunately, I often can't remember what a tag is named while searching (e.g., [windows-2008] vs [windows-server-2008]).

It'd be very helpful to add the excellent tag-autocomplete feature from the Tags textbox into the Search textbox.